# Disaster APIs For Disaster response application

Tags: api

I am looking for Disaster APIs that will provide data on the most current natural disasters. Hurricanes, earthquakes, Tsunamis, droughts ect. Are there any good ones. I found the website http://hisz.rsoe.hu/alertmap/index2.php and was really hoping they had an API but they dont. The map on the site shows all natural disasters and would and displays the data i am looking for. So if anyone knows any APIs where i can get this or similar data please help.

Comment: After days of research i found a few

Comment: Did you happen to find one that works till this day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same problem we have faced a few months ago and decided to build a REST API (http://api.sigimera.org) on top of GDACS.org. GDACS.org is a pretty good information source that classifies different crises types. In the future we plan to extend our platform with other sources and improve tool and library support.

This solution should unify the access to crises and crises relevant information.

Please let me know for what purpose do you need this information and what information are missing or too cumbersome to access. Maybe we can extend our API...

Comment: well I am building a disaster response coordination applications software so i need the data to populate the disaster map and feed data to the users

Comment: Is it possible to have you contacts.. I am interested in using Sigimera

Comment: Is Sigimara still being maintained? I am trying to register, but the reCaptcha is not working

Comment: Appears the sigimera.org is no longer being maintained.

Comment: Hello! Did anyone find a good API, or any way to download at least the historic data?

Comment: I cannot get sigimera to work either, is there any site you guys recommend?

Comment: Sigimera was shutdown and is currently not maintained anymore. Apologize for the inconvenient for all of you that have used it. Unfortunately, it wasn't economical viable anymore.

Answer (score 4):

After Almost a week of research i have found a few that actually are pretty great and goes a great job.
1.http://www.wunderground.com, 2.http://api.sigimera.org
3.http://hurricane.terrapin.com/soap_access.html.en, 4.http://www.seismi.org/api.
Any other good ones are welcome

Answer (score 4):

In case others are still looking for something like this:

[ReliefWeb](http://labs.reliefweb.int/) offers an API. AFAIK they are also UNO backed. Unfortunately, their data isn't very structured, i.e., they offer disaster type and affected countries for all disasters, but no detail infos like 'magnitude' for earthquakes. That can only be found in the description text. But still very useful.

Comment: how recent is the data?

Comment: Mh, simply querying for the latest 'active' disasters give me one from the 5th Nov. 2014 as most recent. Also see: http://reliefweb.int/disasters  And this might be backed by GDACS after all.